# Charts 3.0 - Can not show decimal in BarChart - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, charts, decimal, yaxis

I had store my value in core data and display it at BarChart.
My category amount is in 8.5 and 420.10.

But the display at Bar Chart is 8 and 420.
How should I set the value in decimal?

[image]

```
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

   for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
     let value = values[i] as Double
     print("value=\(value)")
     let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y:value)
     dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
 }

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Total Amount")
chartDataSet.colors = [.red, .yellow, .green, .blue, .brown]
chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
barChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
barChartView.leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true

let chartData = BarChartData()
chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
barChartView.data = chartData
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the answer:

```
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.numberStyle = .decimal
let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)
chartData.setValueFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSNumberFormatter:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
barChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = numberFormatter
```

Try see which is the bar value class and apply it there, probably will have

Comment: Error: Cannot assign value of type 'NumberFormatter' to type 'IAxisValueFormatter'

Comment: Are u using Swift 3?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Swift3

Comment: I get the answer. Please the answer I reply. Thanks